# Python flask stop asyncio loops

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I try to create a Flask rest API with some `asyncio` loops behind working. I was testing it and I can see every time I got a `loop.create_task()` and the `task` start running its like flask server stop it.

He is my code:

```
async def hello_world(sc):
    await asyncio.sleep(sc)
    print("Hello World!",sc)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(hello_world(2))
loop.create_task(hello_world(4))
loop.create_task(hello_world(5))
loop.create_task(hello_world(1))
loop.create_task(hello_world(9))
print("fffffffffffffffffffff")

api.start_server()
```

And I got the following result:

```
 python main.py
 fffffffffffffffffffff
 * Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
 [...]
```

And i expected something like this:

```
python main.py
fffffffffffffffffffff
* Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
[...]
Hello World! 1
Hello World! 2
Hello World! 4
Hello World! 5
Hello World! 9
```

#### Edit

More precise example that I got:

```
import asyncio

async def hello_world(sc):
   await asyncio.sleep(sc)
   print("Hello World!",sc)

async def timer():
    times = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(times)
        times +=1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(timer())
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    hello_world(3),
    hello_world(2), 
    hello_world(4),
    hello_world(5),
))
print("fffffffffffffffffffff")

api.start_server()
```

That I got:

```
λ python main.py
0
Hello World! 2
1
Hello World! 3
2
Hello World! 4
3
Hello World! 5
4
fffffffffffffffffffff
* Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
0
Hello World! 2
1
Hello World! 3
2
Hello World! 4
3
Hello World! 5
4
fffffffffffffffffffff
```

Why stop print `timer()` function?

Comment: try putting all the tasks in a list (name it stream) and then add loop.run_run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(streams))

Comment: i edit whit more precise code

Comment: i might be wrong but according to what i get the timer function is not part of the asyncio.gather group. So i think you should include the timer function as part of the group.